# What's the fastest way to generate matrix vector Beaver triplets?

Tags: multiparty-computation, pseudo-random-correlation

$\vec{u_0} + \vec{u_1} = (M_0 + M_1)\cdot (\vec{v_0} + \vec{v_1})$

$P_i$ gets $(\vec{u_i}, M_i, \vec{v_i})$ where $M_i$ is a matrix , $\vec{u_i},\vec{v_i}$ are vectors, with all entries uniformly distributed over $\mathbb{Z}_{2^k}$